# AWS Lambda: How to respond to http request with json body in node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have to respond to https request with Json body in AWS Lambda API. So, I need to read first the body request and get some data and then to retreive values from external sourse(api) based on those data ans send response back.

I started with this:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const id_ses =  event.queryResult.outputContexts[0].name;
    console.log(id_ses);
    const res = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    console.log(res);
    return  res;
};
//var response = { .... json response
```

When I don't read request body i can send response.. but if i try to get data from the request body, I can't response after it means if I put this two lines

```
const id_ses =  event.queryResult.outputContexts[0].name;
console.log(id_ses);
```

I can not output response to the requested side outside from Lambda... although I have good result in test console...

Any knowledge or some link where I can see sample would be nice....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure like the below to get started:

In the following code, I use two functions as Handler and the `sendToApi` function.

In the handler function, it gets the request from AWS Lambda and reads the body, and pass the name parameter inside the JSON body to the `sendToApi` function. Then, the `sendToApi` function sends a new request to the external API and retrieves the values, and return it to the handler function via `result variable. Then, the handler serves the response.

```js
module.exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const req = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const data = {
        name: req.name
    }
    const result = sendToApi(data);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result),
      };
}

const sendToApi = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let dataString = "";
  
      const options = {
        hostname: "example.com",
        path: "/api/v1",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
  
      const req = https.get(options, (res) => {
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
          dataString += chunk;
        });
  
        res.on("end", (chunk) => {
          dataString = JSON.parse(dataString);
          resolve(dataString);
        });
  
        res.on("error", (e) => {
          console.error(e);
          reject(false);
        });
      });
  
      req.write(querystring.stringify(data));
  
      req.end();
    });
  };
```

For further reading : https://medium.com/better-programming/aws-tutorial-about-node-js-lambda-external-https-requests-logging-and-analyzing-data-e73137fd534c